# Hibernate session synchronization - query cache issue

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, session

This following code of mine is facing synchronization issue with hibernate sessions. There are few parallel threads in my code, each of them own its own hibernate session. The problem is, changes made by one session is not perceived by others for some unknown reasons. The code is located in github [here](https://github.com/thammegowda/hibernate-sync-problem)

## The problem :

Here I explain it with three threads: PRODUCER, CONSUMER_1, CONSUMER_2. The CONSUMER_1 waits for producer to finish its work, even after that, at the end, it doesn't see the changes made by PRODUCER thread. Why is it so?

```
package org.example.hibernate;

import org.example.hibernate.model.User;
import org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    /**
     * This object acts as synchronisation semaphore between threads.
     * (Note : aware that wait within hibernate session is discouraged)
     * Here it is used to show that the consumer tries to read/get after
     * producer has successfully completed the transaction.
     * So here, the producer notifies waiting threads with this object
     */
    public static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    /**
     * user Id is primary key, a random int is suffixed to preserve uniqueness
     * Here, Producer saves an Object of this ID, then consumer tries to read it
     */
    private static final String USER_ID = "user-" + new Random().nextInt(10000);

    /**
     * This is producer thread, it inserts a record and notifies about it to
     * other waiting threads.
     */
    private static Thread PRODUCER = new Thread("producer") {
        // this this creates a user and notifies threads waiting for some event
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HibernateUtil.getInstance().executeInSession(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setId(USER_ID);
                    user.setName("name-" + USER_ID);
                    user.save();
                }
            });
            // outside the session
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                print("Notifying all consumers");
                LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
            print("dying...");
        }
    };

    /**
     * This thread tries to read first, if it misses, then waits for the producer to
     * notify, after it receives notification it tries to read again
     */
    private static Thread CONSUMER_1 = new Thread("consumer_one"){
        // this thread checks if data available(user with specific ID),
        // if not available, waits for the the producer to notify it

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HibernateUtil.getInstance().executeInSession(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        User readUser = User.getById(USER_ID);
                        if(readUser == null) {                  // data not available
                            synchronized (LOCK) {
                                print("Data not available, Waiting for the producer...");
                                LOCK.wait();               // wait for the producer
                                print("Data available");
                            }
                            print("waiting for some more time....");
                            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
                            print("Enough of waiting... now going to read");
                        }
                        readUser = User.getById(USER_ID);
                        if(readUser == null) {
                            // why does this happen??
                            throw new IllegalStateException(
                                    Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                            + " : This shouldn't be happening!!");
                        } else {
                            print("SUCCESS: Read user :" + readUser);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            print("dying...");
        }
    };

    /**
     *   this thread waits for the the producer to notify it, then tries to read
     */
    private static Thread CONSUMER_2 = new Thread("consumer_two"){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HibernateUtil.getInstance().executeInSession(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        synchronized (LOCK) {
                            print("Data not available, Waiting for the producer...");
                            LOCK.wait();                                      // wait for the producer notification
                            print("Data available");
                        }
                        print("waiting for some more time....");
                        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
                        print("Enough of waiting... now going to read");
                        User readUser = User.getById(USER_ID);
                        if(readUser == null) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(
                                    Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                                            " : This shouldn't be happening!!");
                        } else {
                            print("SUCCESS :: Read user :" + readUser);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            print("dying...");
        }
    };


    /**
     * Just another print method to include time stamp and thread name
     * @param msg
     */
    public static void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : "
                + System.currentTimeMillis()+ " : "+ msg);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Initialise hibernate in main thread
        HibernateUtil.getInstance();

        PRODUCER.start();
        CONSUMER_1.start();
        CONSUMER_2.start();

        PRODUCER.join();
        CONSUMER_1.join();
        CONSUMER_2.join();
        print("Exiting....");
    }
}
```

#### And the Output :

```
    INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
[main] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Hibernate Initialised..
consumer_two : 1415036718712 : Data not available, Waiting for the producer...
[producer] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Starting the transaction...
[consumer_two] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Starting the transaction...
[consumer_one] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Starting the transaction...
consumer_one : 1415036718831 : Data not available, Waiting for the producer...
[producer] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Committing the transaction...
producer : 1415036718919 : Notifying all consumers
producer : 1415036718919 : dying...
consumer_one : 1415036718919 : Data available
consumer_one : 1415036718919 : waiting for some more time....
consumer_two : 1415036718919 : Data available
consumer_two : 1415036718919 : waiting for some more time....
[producer] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Session was closed...
consumer_one : 1415036720919 : Enough of waiting... now going to read
consumer_two : 1415036720920 : Enough of waiting... now going to read
Nov 03, 2014 11:15:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache assimilateNewCheckedOutStatement
INFO: Multiply prepared statement! select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.name as name2_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer_one : This shouldn't be happening!!
    at org.example.hibernate.Main$2$1.run(Main.java:79)
    at org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.executeInSession(HibernateUtil.java:60)
    at org.example.hibernate.Main$2.run(Main.java:61)
[consumer_one] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Committing the transaction...
[consumer_one] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Session was closed...
consumer_one : 1415036720931 : dying...
consumer_two : 1415036720940 : SUCCESS :: Read user :User{id='user-422', name='name-user-422'} org.example.hibernate.model.User@4666d804
consumer_two : 1415036720943 : dying...
[consumer_two] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Committing the transaction...
[consumer_two] INFO org.example.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil - Session was closed...
main : 1415036720943 : Exiting....
```

### Here is my hibernate config :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hib_ex</property>
    <property name="connection.username">hibuser</property>
    <property name="connection.password">hibpass</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class"> org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">true</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <mapping class="org.example.hibernate.model.User" />

</session-factory>
```

### The hibernate Utility

```
public enum HibernateUtil {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private final String CONFIG_FILE = "hibernate.xml";

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    HibernateUtil(){
        LOG.info("Initialising hibernate...");
        URL configUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(CONFIG_FILE);
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        try {
            configuration.configure(configUrl);
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            LOG.info("Hibernate Initialised..");
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not init hibernate!");
        }
    }

    public Session getSession(){
        if(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() != null
                && sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen()) {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } else {
            LOG.info("Opening a session");
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
    }

    public void executeInSession(Runnable runnable){
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        if(!transaction.isActive()){
            LOG.info("Starting the transaction...");
            transaction.begin();
        }
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                LOG.info("Committing the transaction...");
                transaction.commit();
            } else {
                LOG.info("Transaction was committed...");
            }
            if(session.isOpen()){
                LOG.info("Closing the session...");
                session.close();
            } else {
                LOG.info("Session was closed...");
            }
        }
    }

    public static HibernateUtil getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Please help me understand :
- Why CONSUMER_1 thread's [`User.getById(userId)`](https://github.com/thammegowda/hibernate-sync-problem/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/hibernate/Main.java#L76) returns `null` even after the PRODUCER thread's transaction successfully completes? 
- How CONSUMER_2 thread's [`User.getById(userId)`](https://github.com/thammegowda/hibernate-sync-problem/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/hibernate/Main.java#L113) is able to get the same object almost at the same time when CONSUMER_1 is getting null ?

To save your valuable time, get the complete code from [github repo](https://github.com/thammegowda/hibernate-sync-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your database transaction isolation guarantees repeatable reads. Since the consumer 1 start by reading the entity and finds it is null, and then later executes the same query in the same transaction, the same result is returned: null. Transactions run in isolation, that's the *I* is *ACID*. Your transactions should be as short as possible. You shouldn't let the transaction and the session opened when you found that the expected entity is not available. So, instead of doing

```
open session and transaction
    get entity
    wait for entity to be available
    get entity again
close the transaction and session
```

you should do

```
open session and transaction
    get entity
close the transaction and session
wait for entity to be available
open session and transaction
    get entity again
close the transaction and session
```